# yFinance multi ticker information not working

Tags: python, api, yfinance

I'm having trouble getting multi ticker info through yFinance.  I want to establish teh multi ticker method rather that iterating through each stock individually so i can use the session function and increase performance.

im using yfinance 0.1.63 and python 364.

My code is this

```
import yfinance as yf

tickers = yf.Tickers('msft aapl goog')
print(tickers.tickers.GOOG.actions)
print(tickers.tickers.AAPL.history(period="1mo"))
print(tickers.tickers.MSFT.info)
```

But my output is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\opt\jobs\python\multitech.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(tickers.tickers.GOOG.actions)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'GOOG'
```

this seems to work for others but does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It took some time poking around, but came up with solution.  Using python 3.8 and yfinance 0.1.63 both under the Anaconda package.

```
import yfinance as yf

tickers = yf.Tickers('msft aapl goog')

print(tickers.tickers['GOOG'].actions)
print(tickers.tickers['AAPL'].history(period="1mo"))
print(tickers.tickers['MSFT'].info)
```